# Basic Authentication 401 Unauthorized error calling restful web service

Tags: rest

I am using spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar which contains Spring RestTemplate.java.
I wrote 4 junit test case to call the "https" basic authentication restfull web services. I already dealt with the "https" issue by registering the certificate to the java keystore cacerts file. Now I getting "http 401 Unauthorized" error when I call the restfull web services through java but not through soapUI or postman:

In Junit test case 2("testLocalCreateABCVersion2()"), I used custom ContextAwareHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java class. Which I provided at the bottom.

In Junit test case 3("testLocalCreateABCVersion3()"), I used custom BasicAuthRestTemplate.java which I provided below.

In Junit test case 4(testLocalCreateABCVersion4()), I used org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient and set client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true) to true. This HttpClients comes from commons-httpClient-3.1.jar and does why the "setAuthenticationPreemptive" exists. In org.apache.httpcomponents.httpClient_4.5.3.jar it doesnt't contain the method setAuthenticationPreemptive.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!

```
                    import java.util.ArrayList;
                    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
                    import java.util.List;

                    import org.junit.Test;
                    import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
                    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
                    import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
                    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
                    import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
                    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
                    import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

                    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
                    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
                    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
                    import com.journaldev.spring.controller.EmpRestURIConstants;

                    import com.abc.model.Employee;
                    import com.test.TestRequestPost;
                    import com.test.costcontrolservice.AbcResponse;

                    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
                    import org.apache.commons.codeabc.binary.Base64;
                    import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
                    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;
                    import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
                    import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
                    import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
                    import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
                    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
                    import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
                    import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
                    import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme;
                    import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicAuthCache;
                    import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
                    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
                    import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
                    import org.apache.http.osgi.services.HttpClientBuilderFactory;
                    import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;

                    import javax.net.ssl.*;
                    import java.io.*;
                    import java.security.KeyManagementException;
                    import java.security.KeyStore;
                    import java.security.MessageDigest;
                    import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
                    import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
                    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
                    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
                    import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;



                    public class TestExample1 
                    {

                        public static final String SERVER_URI_ABC_POST ="https://abc/rest/testservice/abc";

                        @Test
                        public void testLocalCreateABCVersion1()
                        {
                        try
                            {


                            String plainCreds = "idAbc:Password-Test";
                            byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
                            byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
                            String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
                                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                                headers.add("Authorization", "Basic"+base64Creds);
                                HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

                                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

                                TestRequestPost TestRequestPost = new TestRequestPost();



                                //with basic authentication
                                ResponseEntity<AbcResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(SERVER_URI_ABC_POST ,HttpMethod.POST,request, AbcResponse.class,TestRequestPost);

                                assertNotNull(response);
                            }
                        catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                System.out.println("e:"+e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                        @Test
                        public void testLocalCreateABCVersion2()
                        {
                        try
                            {


                            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            String userId ="idAbc";
                            String password = "Password-Test";

                            BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =  new BasicCredentialsProvider();
                            credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userId, password));
                            client.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);

                            ContextAwareHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory customFactory = new ContextAwareHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
                            String host = "abc/rest/testservice/abc";
                            int port = 443;
                            HttpHost targetHost = null;
                            targetHost = new HttpHost(host, port, "http");



                            // Create AuthCache instance
                            BasicAuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
                            // Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local auth cache
                            BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
                            authCache.put(targetHost, basicAuth);

                            // Add AuthCache to the execution context
                            BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                            localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);    

                            customFactory.setHttpContext(localContext);
                            RestTemplate restTemplate =  new RestTemplate(customFactory);


                            String plainCreds = "idAbc:Password-Test";
                            byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
                            byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
                            String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

                            byte[] token = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(plainCreds.getBytes());
                            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                            headers.add("Authorization", "Basic"+new String(token));
                            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
                            TestRequestPost TestRequestPost = new TestRequestPost();


                            //without basic authentication
                            //AbcResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject(SERVER_URI_ABC_POST , TestRequestPost, AbcResponse.class);

                            //with basic authentication
                            ResponseEntity<AbcResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(SERVER_URI_ABC_POST ,HttpMethod.POST,request, AbcResponse.class,TestRequestPost);

                            assertNotNull(response);
                            }
                        catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                System.out.println("e:"+e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                        @Test
                        public void testLocalCreateABCVersion3()
                        {
                        try
                            {


                            String plainCreds = "idAbc:Password-Test";
                            byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
                            byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
                            String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
                            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                            headers.add("Authorization", "Basic"+base64Creds);
                            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

                            RestTemplate restTemplate = new BasicAuthRestTemplate("idAbc","Password-Test");
                            TestRequestPost TestRequestPost = new TestRequestPost();

                            //without basic authentication
                            //  AbcResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject(SERVER_URI_ABC_POST , TestRequestPost, AbcResponse.class);

                            //with basic authentication
                            ResponseEntity<AbcResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(SERVER_URI_ABC_POST ,HttpMethod.POST,request, AbcResponse.class,TestRequestPost);

                            assertNotNull(response);
                            }
                        catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                System.out.println("e:"+e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                        @Test
                        public void testLocalCreateABCVersion4()
                        {
                        try
                            {


                            String plainCreds = "idAbc:Password-Test";
                            byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
                            byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
                            String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
                            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                            headers.add("Authorization", "Basic"+base64Creds);

                            org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient client = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient();
                            client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
                            UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("idAbc","Password-Test");
                            client.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope("abc",433,AuthScope.ANY_REALM),credentials);
                            CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory commons = new CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
                            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(commons);

                            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);


                            TestRequestPost TestRequestPost = new TestRequestPost();

                            ResponseEntity<CostControlResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(SERVER_URI_ABC_POST ,HttpMethod.POST,request, AbcResponse.class.class,TestRequestPost);
                            assertNotNull(response);
                            }
                        catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                System.out.println("e:"+e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }


                    }
```

ContextAwareHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java:

```
            import java.net.URI;



        import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
        import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
        import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
        import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
        //import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
        public class ContextAwareHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory extends
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory {
        private HttpContext httpContext;

        public ContextAwareHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClient httpClient){
        super(httpClient);
        }

        protected org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext createHttpContext(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri) {
        //Ignoring the URI and method.
        return httpContext;
        }

        public void setHttpContext(HttpContext httpContext) {
        this.httpContext = httpContext;
        }
        }
```

BasicAuthRestTemplate.java:

```
                import org.springframework.http.HttpRequest;
            import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestExecution;
            import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
            import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
            import org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory;
            import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

            import java.io.IOException;
            //import java.util.Base64; original
            import java.util.Collections;
            import java.util.List;
            import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; //new

            public class BasicAuthRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {

                public BasicAuthRestTemplate(String username, String password) {
                    addAuthentication(username, password);
                }

                private void addAuthentication(String username, String password) {
                    if (username == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = Collections
                            .<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> singletonList(
                                    new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(username, password));
                    setRequestFactory(new InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory(getRequestFactory(),
                            interceptors));
                }

                private static class BasicAuthorizationInterceptor implements
                        ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

                    private final String username;

                    private final String password;

                    public BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(String username, String password) {
                        this.username = username;
                        this.password = (password == null ? "" : password);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body,
                            ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException 
                    {
                        /* original code
                        byte[] token = Base64.getEncoder().encode(
                                (this.username + ":" + this.password).getBytes());
                        request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(token));
                        return execution.execute(request, body);
                        */
                        String plainCreds = "idAbc:Password-Test";
                    byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
                    byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
                    String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
                    request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(base64Creds));
                    return execution.execute(request, body);

                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: I don't have to use Spring Rest, does anybody have a link for restfull rest service client in jersey or apache cxf or spring RestTemplate or just plain Apache Client.java that can call a restful web services with basic authentication. Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!

Answer (score 0):

try with below link, it helps me on the RestClient

http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-restful/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/

Here is how I do it. replace TODO with your data

1) create new instance from Sprint RestTemplate.  you can config it as Spring bean too

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

2) set up the security header

```
protected MultiValueMap<String, String> addSecurityHeader() {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
    headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
    headers.add("Authorization", TODO_BasicAuthCode);

    return headers;
}
```

3)  HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<>(TODO, addSecurityHeader());

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(getTicketUrl, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: Thank you providing the link. Greatly appreciated it!! But I don't see in the link any contents about basic authentication. I see examples how to pass get vs post for RestFul web services using spring RestTemplate.